# Shopify Liquid: Add A Product to the Customers Cart using a Custom Section

Tags: e-commerce, shopify, shopify-template

How to add a product to cart in a custom section.

I have this custom section where multiple products are being selected, and I want to add them all to the cart when the customer clicks buy.

I'm guessing there is a form used to `POST` products into the customers cart?

#### Access Products

```
{{ for collection in collections }}
    {{ for product in collection.products }}
        <input type="checkbox" name="{{product.title}}" value="{{product.title}}" > {{product.title}}<br>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

#### Add Products to cart

Do I use a `<form>`, or is there a `shopify tag` that I can use to create a form? I do not understand how to add these selected items to the customer's cart.

Comment: You can use SALES CHANNELS -> Buy Button to add n number of products directly to customer cart.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much you can do this.

```
<form action="/cart/add" method="post">
  {%- for variant in product.variants -%}
    <input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="{{ variant.id }}" />
  {%- endfor -%}
  <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" />
</form>
```

Where you **must** name the inputs `name="id[]"` and not `name="{{product.title}}"`.

Comment: Note that, when using the `id[]` method to add-to-cart, all products added in that form submission will have the same quantity and the same line-item properties (if any).